# Axis label placement

Tags: r, graphics

I've got a probably fairly simple question.
I want to put my y-axis label horizontally above the y-axis, in stead of the default (vertically alongside the y-axis). This probably requires a par() command, but which one?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `par` is what you want. You could just adjust the default, exclude the label of the y-axis with `ylab = ""` and manually add your text with marginal text input (`mtext`).
Example:

```
xx <- 1:20
yy <- 55 + 50 * xx - 3 * xx ^ 2

plot(x = xx, y = yy, type = "l", ylab="")
mtext("yy", side = 3, at = -1)
```

Or as a function:

```
newplot <- function(xx, yy) {
  plot(x = xx, y = yy, type = "l", ylab="")
  mtext(deparse(substitute(yy)), side = 3,
    at = - sum(range(xx)) / range(xx)[2])
}
```